# WinCE 6.0 connecting to PC via ActiveSync/Window Mobile Device Center C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, tcp, activesync, wmdc

I am developing a WinCE application (.Net 3.5) which allow connection to terminal via TCPIP, Serial Port and USB.

TCPIP and Serial Port is done but USB is problematic. As the client need to see proof on USB can be done, we need to prove that we can send Hex command through ActiveSync.

I have google for some time and found that ActiveSync/WMDC will provide IP to allow connection with each other. The problem is i couldn't ping or connect via C# socket from PC  to WinCE via ActiveSync/WMDC.

The only thing i know is that my WinCE IP when connecting to PC is:
IP Address     : 192.168.55.101
Subnet Mask    : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.55.100
Primary DNS    : 127.0.0.1

Below is my WinCE server code that i use to allow all connection from ActiveSync. I am reusing my TCPIP code to connect to ActiveSync.

```
_listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port));             
_listener.Listen(100);
_listener.BeginAccept(ConnectionReady, null);
```

Is there anything that i have missed to allow connection with each other? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that it is workable but not in a straight forward way.

Normally we will set the PC as Server while WinCE as Slave. In this case, it is in backwards. WinCE will be the host while PC will be the slave.

Below is my code that i have used to declare and start the connection:

```
        private void SetUSBSerialPort()
        {
            try
            {
                usbSerialPort = new USBSerialPort(config.terminal_tcpip_port);
                usbSerialPort.OnReceiveData += new USBSerialPort.EventOnReceiveData(usbSerialPort_OnReceiveData);
                usbSerialPort.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

And below is the class that i used to connect PC and WinCE via ActiveSync:

```
public class ConnectionStateUSB
    {
        internal Socket _conn;
        //internal TcpServiceProvider _provider;
        internal byte[] _buffer;

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Tells you the IP Address of the remote host.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public EndPoint RemoteEndPoint
        {
            get { return _conn.RemoteEndPoint; }
        }

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Returns the number of bytes waiting to be read.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public int AvailableData
        {
            get { return _conn.Available; }
        }

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Tells you if the socket is connected.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public bool Connected
        {
            get { return _conn.Connected; }
        }

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Reads data on the socket, returns the number of bytes read.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_conn.Available > 0)
                    return _conn.Receive(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None);
                else return 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Sends Data to the remote host.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public bool Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            try
            {
                _conn.Send(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Ends connection with the remote host.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public void EndConnection()
        {
            if (_conn != null && _conn.Connected)
            {
                _conn.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                _conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    class USBSerialPort
    {
        Socket newsock;
        Socket client;
        int port;
        IPAddress ipaddress;
        private AsyncCallback ConnectionReady;
        private AsyncCallback AcceptConnection;
        private AsyncCallback ReceivedDataReady;
        private ConnectionStateUSB currentST;
        public bool IsConnected = false;

        public USBSerialPort(int _port)
        {
            port = _port;
            //ConnectionReady = new AsyncCallback(ConnectionReady_Handler);
            //AcceptConnection = new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnection_Handler);
            //ReceivedDataReady = new AsyncCallback(ReceivedDataReady_Handler);
        }

        public void Start()
        {            
            try
            {
                ipaddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("ppp_peer").AddressList[0];
                newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, port);
                newsock.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), newsock);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                this.Stop();
            }
            finally
            {
                //net_stream = null;
                //tcp_client = null;
            }
        }

        void Connected(IAsyncResult iar)
        {            
            try
            {
                client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(iar);

                ConnectionStateUSB st = new ConnectionStateUSB();
                st._conn = client;
                st._buffer = new byte[4];
                //Queue the rest of the job to be executed latter
                //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AcceptConnection, st);
                currentST = st;
                //conStatus.Text = "Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                if (client.Connected)
                    client.BeginReceive(st._buffer, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None,
                                  new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), st);                
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                IsConnected = false;
                //conStatus.Text = "Error connecting";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsConnected = false;
            }
        }

        void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionStateUSB remote = (ConnectionStateUSB)iar.AsyncState;
                remote._conn.EndReceive(iar);
                try
                {                    
                    this.OnReceiveData(remote);
                    IsConnected = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    IsConnected = false;
                }
                //int recv = remote.EndReceive(iar);
                //string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                //results.Items.Add(stringData);
                if (remote.Connected)
                    remote._conn.BeginReceive(remote._buffer, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None,
                                  new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), remote);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Stop();
            }
        }

        public void SendData(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                bool a = currentST.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsConnected = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Error!\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public void SendData(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data + Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte(3)));
                bool a = currentST.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                msg = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsConnected = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Error!\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }


        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Shutsdown the server
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public void Stop()
        {
            //lock (this)
            //{
                if (newsock != null)
                    newsock.Close();
                if (client != null)
                    client.Close();
                if (currentST != null)
                {
                    currentST._conn.Close();
                    currentST = null;
                }
                IsConnected = false;
            //}
        }

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Gets executed when the server accepts a new connection.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public delegate void EventOnAcceptConnection(ConnectionStateUSB socket);
        public event EventOnAcceptConnection OnAcceptConnection;

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Gets executed when the server detects incoming data.
        /// This method is called only if OnAcceptConnection has already finished.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public delegate void EventOnReceiveData(ConnectionStateUSB socket);
        public event EventOnReceiveData OnReceiveData;

        /// <SUMMARY>
        /// Gets executed when the server needs to shutdown the connection.
        /// </SUMMARY>
        public delegate void EventOnDropConnection(ConnectionStateUSB socket);
        public event EventOnDropConnection OnDropConnection;
    }
```

Hope this help.